# AJAX Built and Deployment Environment especially javascript and css min, full versions

Tags: javascript, css, deployment, repository, environment

Currently I have one QA server to run on, svn update can be run there to test the code that everyone commits to subversion.
The issue I have seen with more and more javascript and css that the min or full version that get compiled, eg:

- Build tool: Jake
- JS compressor: UglifyJS
- CSS optimizer: CSSO

either have to manually be updated/compiled just before promotion to production servers or we just have the min/full version on our svn but that would be not so great.
The way I see an approach would be:
* keep the full/split css java script files outside of the path where web served content sits, subversion or trac builds the min/full version on submit/trigger.

Has anyone further automated this process? 
How do you separate your full source/full version/min version as not to mess up final deployment? When do you compile the min version? 
Only at the last step before going to production? 
Where do you leave the original source, it cannot live right next to the web served other files, in my example php files?

Answer (score 0):

Just been dealing with something similar myself.  If I understand your question correctly you're looking to have unminified files in a local or dev environment but have them minified upon deployment.  There are, of course, many different ways that you can go about this, and we're currently working on a better solution but I'll give you an example of a project I just finished up...

Uses symfony 1.4, YUI Compressor, and git.

I have a symfony task (php cli script) set up to run YUI Compressor on a given list of css and js files, which get dumped into min.css and min.js in the appropriate directories.  The script simply dumps all of the contents of the listed files into one big file and minifies them.  Then symfony is set to only use min.js.  Of course, debugging minified files can be a pain, so another option is to skip minifying on your local or dev boxes and just keep them as a combined file.  Personally I have it minifying anyway because Chrome's "Pretty print" option works well enough for me most of the time, although it's not 'ideal'.

I've created a local post-commit and server side post-merge script for git that simply runs the symfony task so the files are automatically updated whenever you commit locally or do a git pull on the server, so any changes made inside the js/css files are updated when committing. The only pain point of this is having to manually run the minify script whenever you've updated locally but haven't yet committed.

An alternative to keep unminified code on local/dev would require some more coding so that it is environment specific, which is certainly doable but I've just been lazy with it thus far as this works well enough for now :)

Answer (score 0):

I have taken the following convention-based approach and it works well for me for traditional web-development as well as for mobile apps and offline HTML5 mobile apps.

**Conventions**

- All non-minified/full-version js/css scripts are named with .debug.js or .debug.css extensions.
  *Example:* global.debug.js and global.debug.css
- All references to js/css in html reference non-debug versions: global.js or global.css

**Process**

- I use a custom MSBuild task to minify js (using AjaxMin, but you could use YUI Compressor or others) to the following naming convention *.release.js or *.release.css
  (Example: global.release.js).
- After minification into the *.release.js files. I have one more MSBuild task that calls a simple batch file (JS.bat) that accepts the current Configuration (Debug or Release) and copies either the debug (full-source version) or the release (minified) version to the normal destination.

Here's the sample MSBuild tasks I add to my project file to accomplish the minification and call to my batch file:

```
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\MicrosoftAjax\ajaxmin.tasks" />
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
      <DebugJS Include="**\*.debug.js" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <AjaxMin SourceFiles="@(DebugJS)" SourceExtensionPattern="\.debug.js$" TargetExtension=".release.js" />
    <Exec Command="JS.bat $(Configuration)" />
  </Target>
```

For example, assuming:

- I'm in Debug mode
- and I have a global.debug.js file (full-source version that I work in)
- When I build my project, global.debug.js get's minified into global.release.js
- Since I'm in the Debug mode configuration, global.debug.js will get copied to global.js (which is what my html references) and, therefore, I'll have the full-source version when debugging
- If I switch to Release mode configuration, then global.release.js (the minified version) gets copied to global.js and this is what I would want for release/deployment to production.

Here's the simple batch script (JS.bat) that I use to handle the copy of the Debug or Release script based on the passed argument:

```
@Echo off
REM ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
REM <summary>
REM     Script used to copy the Debug (or Release) javascript files to the runtime location
REM </summary>
REM <history>
REM     <change date="9/22/2010" author="Adam Anderly">Created</change>
REM </history>
REM ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
REM Grab the first argument as variable Config (Debug/Release)
SET Config=%~1
REM The loop below is used to get the Length of the Config variable
REM The Length variable is then used in the substring function on Line 22
for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%a in ( 
 '^(echo."%Config%"^& echo.!@#^)^|findstr /O /C:"!@#" ' 
) do set /a Length=%%a-5 + 4
FOR /R %%i IN (*.%Config%.js) DO CALL :REN "%%i"
GOTO :END
:REN
    SET File=%~f1
    REM Set File2 variable to the runtime filename (minus .debug or .release)
    CALL SET File2=%%File:~0,-%Length%%%.js
    REM First make sure the destination file is not read-only
    IF EXIST "%File2%" ATTRIB /S -R "%File2%"
    REM Finally, we copy the current debug|release file to the runtime file
    COPY /Y "%File%" "%File2%"
:END
```

The batch script above works recursively so you can have nested folders of js or css and it still works.

While I'm using MSBuild, you could certainly incorporate this batch file into your process using a different build tool (previously I did the same using NAnt).

Hope that helps!

Adam